# Same code/ feature for different files (user friendly approach )

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a little bit of code for VBA-Excel.
Goal; that when a coworker open a file and saves it under a certain name. This new file will have all the buttons and VBA code that I made.

Please note that all subsequent files will have the same format as the one I made my code in.

Comment: Can you clarify? None of the sentences are questions, so it's hard to tell what you're looking for. If you have an issue with that code, please share it, thanks!

Comment: If the user doesn't change anything before saving as a different name, everything should still work.  Qualifying commands with `ThisWorkbook` will overcome changes to workbook name.  Using sheet code names like `Sheet1` should protect against changed sheet names.  Anticipating all other possible user changes may be difficult.